# Get a list of s3 buckets associated with amazon access key using powershell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I have tried googling how I could retrieve a list of available s3 buckets associated with an Amazon Access Key, but either I am searching the wrong terms, or I haven't went through enough results.

I have an access key and secret key, but I do not know the bucket name(s) associated with either the account or IAM user.

How can I get a list of the bucket names available using Powershell and AWS Tools?

Comment: What information specifically are you looking for?  Buckets that are visible to that credential holder, or buckets that credential holder is responsible for?

Comment: Hi Anthony, I am looking for buckets that are 'visible' and accessible to user associated with access/secret key. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you've already set up your [AWS Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html) the way you want, you can simply call [Get-S3Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3Bucket.html).  This invokes ListBuckets, and returns a collection of [S3Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TS3S3Bucket_NET4_5.html) objects that are visible to you:

Example:

```
# With credentials stored in the SDK store:
PS C:\> Get-S3Bucket

CreationDate                                                BucketName
------------                                                ----------
5/20/2015 2:00:00 PM                                        MyBucket1
5/21/2015 4:00:00 PM                                        MyBucket2

 # With credentials passed inline:    
PS C:\> Get-S3Bucket -AccessKey "accKey" -SecretKey "secKey" -Region "us-east-1"

CreationDate                                                BucketName
------------                                                ----------
5/20/2015 2:00:00 PM                                        MyBucket1
5/21/2015 4:00:00 PM                                        MyBucket2
```

Comment: Beautifully simple! Thank you for the succinct informative response. This is exactly what I was looking and hoping for!